# ngx-bootstrap Dropdown failed

Tags: angular, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown'; this don't work.

I didn't find "dropdown" in my folder[image]

Thank you for helping me!

I tried to add this component by myself, but It always failed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your vs code terminal then try installing ngx bootstrap again

> npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Answer (score 0):

You need to update ngx-bootstrap:

npm i ngx-bootstrap@10.3.0 --save